# how to create an xml file for each record

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have a table called test and it has n number of columns including one flag column. Now my question is about, how to create an xml file for each record and at the same time i need to update the flag column as well.

Consider the below table

sno details flag

1,'xyz','y'
2,'abc','y' 
3,'def','y'
4,'ghi','y'
5,'jkl','y' 
6,'mno','y'

Now i want to create xml files say xmlfile1 for the record 1,'xyz','y' and need to update the flag status as 'n' in the table and the samething i need to do it for all other records.

Can anyone help me on the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think JAXB is perfect solution for generating XML and you have to use java code to update flag. Sample code http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: Hi, I want the program in PLSQL..,

Comment: try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be7ac/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
with xml_source as (select 1 id, 'xyz' val, 'y' flag
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 2, 'abc', 'y'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 3, 'def', 'y'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 4, 'ghi', 'y'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 5, 'jkl', 'y'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 6, 'mno', 'y' from dual)

 select xmlagg(xmlelement(TABLE_NAME, (xmlelement(TABLE_ROW, XMLATTRIBUTES(x.id AS ID), xmlforest(x.val as Value)))))
  from xml_source x
```

You can also read about [Generating XML Data from the Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB1600).

Comment: Hi Mikron Tnx it works fine .., but i want the procedure that copies the generated files into one directory and update the flag column value as 'n'

Comment: For the writing the generated xml, have a look at [utl_file package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS069), after successfull export, You can make an [update](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm) of Your table based on the rows You select in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion.. i did it like below

create table test(sno number,details varchar2(20),flag varchar2(1) constraint flag_cons check (flag in('y','n')));

insert into test values(1,'xyz','y');

insert into test values(2,'abc','y');

insert into test values(3,'def','y');

insert into test values(4,'ghi','y');

insert into test values(5,'jkl','y');

insert into test values(6,'mno','y');

CREATE or replace DIRECTORY xml_dir as xxxxx;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE xml_example 
IS

```
CURSOR query_str is select * from test ;


row_type test%rowtype;

xml_file clob;

v_MyFileHandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
```

BEGIN
    for row_type in query_str 
     LOOP

```
     select dbms_xmlquery.getxml('select * from test where sno='||row_type.sno,0) into xml_file from dual;

     v_MyFileHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('XML_DIR','xmlfile'||to_char(query_str%rowcount),'w');

     UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_MyFileHandle,xml_file  );

     UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_MyFileHandle);

     update test set flag='n' where sno=row_type.sno ;

END LOOP;
```

END xml_example;